# Generate table DDL from DB2 11.1 LUW

Tags: db2, ddl

I would like to generate DDL script file for a table.  I would love to do this with SQL statement, but I would except a CLPPLUS or CLP solution.
Can this be done with db2look?  I have tried but always get way too much detail.

`db2look -d 'MY_DB' -z 'DB2INST1' -t 'MY_TABLE' -e -o MY_TABLE.sql`

`db2look -d 'MY_DB' -z 'DB2INST1' -t 'MY_TABLE' -e -noview -nofed -x -o MY_TABLE.sql`

I want only the basic DDL (the create table statement), I do not want any on the additional details about the table.

Comment: I do not think there is any way to get just the create table statement.

Comment: How about filtering the ouput with a tool like awk?

Comment: Thank you @mao for the SQL solution I was looking for, but I could not run it due to permission issues.  So, the shell script using awk worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make `db2look` print DDL for the `CREATE TABLE` statement only.
If you are on Linux / Unix, you may try the following:

```
db2look -d MY_DB -z DB2INST1 -t MY_TABLE -e -noview -nofed \
| awk -v RS='' '/CREATE TABLE/' \
| tee MY_TABLE.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the `db2look` tool has limitations , one of them being that it won't give you specifically the subset of information you want. So you can post process the output (as suggested by Mark Barinstein).

Depending on your reason for wanting only the 'create table' DDL, sometimes, all you need is to use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...` 
to achieve a result, especially if you are using declared global temporary tables. With that method, there's no need to use `db2look`.

For Db2-LUW - there is another approach with SQL if your permissions and authorisations are correct.

For Db2-Linux/Unix/Windows, there is an undocumented stored procedure called `SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL`, which writes data to `SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO` . If the grants/permissions are correct for your account then you could use this technique with plain SQL to selectively extract from `SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO`. The instance-owner will normally already have the required permissions (which include execute rights on the procedures and rights on sequence `db2look_token` along with select access to `systools.db2look_info` and related view, see below for grants. )

Suppose I have a table called `USER1.MYTAB` whose DDL I want to extract with plain SQL, here is sample code:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
create or replace variable  my_ddl varchar(1024)@

begin
    declare v_out_token integer default 0;

    call sysproc.db2lk_generate_ddl('-e -t USER1.MYTAB', v_out_token);

    select substr(sql_stmt,1,1024)
    into my_ddl
    from systools.db2look_info
    where op_token = v_out_token
    and sql_operation='CREATE' with ur;

end@


values(my_ddl)@
```

The popular DBeaver GUI tool uses this technique, as do some other tools. You can post-process the contents of the SQL_STMT column in SQL also.

If your auth-id lacks permission, then contact the DBA or SECADM and ask for the following :

```
grant usage on sequence SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_TOKEN to user your-authid;


grant select, update, delete, insert on table SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO to user your-authid ;

grant select on table SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO_V to user your-authid ;
```

You might consider voting on a suggestion for IBM to improve to document this interface:

https://ibm-data-and-ai.ideas.aha.io/ideas/DB24LUW-I-962

Unfortunately IBM has given this a low priority for 'future consideration', but the more people that vote perhaps someone at IBM will notice.