# How to get CREATE TABLE Statement from existing table in db2?

Tags: sql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using DB2 and Oracle SQL Developer.
How to get the CREATE TABLE Statements from the existing tables?

There are too many tables and it will be a very lengthy process to do manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate table DDL from DB2 11.1 LUW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231965/generate-table-ddl-from-db2-11-1-luw)

Answer (score 1):

There is a special [db2look](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2look-db2-statistics-ddl-extraction-tool) utility for DDL extraction in Db2. You may refer to its options and their meaning at this link.

If you want SQL access to its capabilities, you may use the `SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL` stored procedure supporting most of the utility's options. The routine has an output parameter getting "invocation number" int value after its call.
In case of a single table:

```
CALL SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL ('-e -noview -t MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE', ?);

SELECT SQL_STMT
FROM SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO_V
WHERE OP_TOKEN = <value_of_output_parameter_from_call_above>
ORDER BY OP_SEQUENCE;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLDeveloper if you can see the table there's the initial Create Table Statement in the SQL Tab

[image: SQLDev - SQL Tab]

You should do that for each table, this is a way to do it but I'm not sure it's fast enough for you.

Comment: Hi. I can not see the SQL Tab for any of my table. The only tabs I can see are Columns, Data, Keys, Constraints and Indexes. Could you help with that?

Comment: Go to View -> Editor -> SQL. Can you see it from here?

Comment: There is no option of "Editor" in View

Comment: What's the version of SQLDev you are using? I'm using Version: 18.1.0.095.1630; If you are using an older version, I suggest you to update it to a newest and see if you have this option.

Comment: I am using Version 3.1.07 and Build MAIN-07.42

Comment: Apparently in your version is absent this functionality. If you can't update the client, I suggest you to follow another suggested solution.