# Python ibm_db equivalent of db2look

Tags: python, db2

SO I am using `ibm_db` library for fetch necessary information. Now I want to get the full table creation script along with index and all. I can see there is one `db2look` command to generate the same

```bash
db2look -d some_db -z xxxx -t xxxx -e -i xxxx-w xxxx -o script.sql
```

Is there an equivalent thing in ibm_db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not an exact equivalent in the python `ibm_db` for the `db2look` tool.

Alternative approaches exist.

Nothing (except suitable authorities/permissions) prevents you from running a stored procedure that exececutes (i.e. shells out to) db2look on the database-server and return its output to the python script.

If the workstation running python ibm_db also has the Db2 fat client installed, then python can directly run `db2look` as long as your Db2 client has the relevant database(s) catalogued.

You can also use python to execute an undocumented DB2-LUW stored procedure (`sysproc.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL()`) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231965/generate-table-ddl-from-db2-11-1-luw), subject to your account having relevant rights.

You can also write your own queries for the catalog views (i.e. re-invent the wheel), in order to generate the DDL, which lets you do whatever you want.

Comment: yup, I was thinking the same to run ddl from python, but the issue is I am developing on windows and the code will be deployed on linux. So to make life easier I was thinking if there is any way to use ibm_db directly.