# Generate DDL of a table through a statement in DBeaver

Tags: db2, ddl, dbeaver

I'm looking for a way to generate the DDL of a table in DBeaver, I'm using Db2 for IBM as database, through a statement. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate table DDL from DB2 11.1 LUW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231965/generate-table-ddl-from-db2-11-1-luw)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to locate the table in the tree view and select it. Then right click and choose:

```
Generate SQL
    DDL
```

If you want to create DDL with information from the information schema, you are probably better of using a host language such as python and read information from SYSCAT.TABLES, SYSCAT.COLUMNS, SYSCAT.INDEXES, SYSCAT.TABCONST and so forth.